# How can I produce custom vector based buttons in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, button

I want to create some vector based buttons which resemble the button design shown below:

[image: buttons]

I can just take a button and treat it as a bitmap and change text and appearance, but the output doesn't look professional. If I have a vector of the same design, it can easily be re-sized and modified without loss in quality.

How can I create vector versions of these in Photoshop CS6?

Comment: Photoshop will not output vectors, this would have to be taken care of with Illustrator or Inkscape.

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said, Photoshop won't create a true vector image. Although you can still create a shape like that in Photoshop that you can re-size with better results than re-sizing a PNG, GIF, or JPG.

1. Create a basic shape using the **Rounded Rectangle Tool**
2. Hold down the **Pen Tool** and select the add anchor points option
3. Click on the sides of the rectangle to add anchor points
4. Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) to move the anchor points to get the curls you want

[**Photoshop Help / Editing paths**](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector, yes, it will resize at any scale without losing quality. However, you'll need to jump into illustrator to do this.

When using a bitmap, it should still only be deteriorating quality if you're scaling the image up, or saving it as a compressed format, like a jpg or a gif.

Comment: Scaling down doesn't always treat your rasters kindly either. Stick to vectors when you know you'll have to scale. Export to raster when you're done.